# How does np.outer help in creating a filter kernel?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I was trying the [filter2D](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#void%20filter2D(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20int%20ddepth,%20InputArray%20kernel,%20Point%20anchor,%20double%20delta,%20int%20borderType)) function with OpenCV using my own kernel:

```
kernel = np.array([1,3,4,5,2]) / 11

cv2.filter2D(img, -1, kernel)
```

and it works fine. I also saw a snippet where the same thing was done as follows:

```
kernel = np.array([1,3,4,5,2]) / 11
kernel = np.outer(kernel, kernel)

cv2.filter2D(img, -1, kernel)
```

I am not sure what does the second approach do? What is really happening here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very briefly, your first kernel is 1D, np.outer creates a 2D kernel.

In more detail: (I don't have open cv, I'm using scipy / PIL instead, but this should essentially be equivalent.)

```
>>> import numpy as np                                                                
>>> from scipy import misc, ndimage                  
>>>
# get example image, decimate it a bit 
>>> f = misc.face()[::4,::4]                    
>>> 
# create a simple 1D kernel (a triangle)
>>> kernel = 16 - np.abs(np.arange(-15, 16))                                                           
>>> kernel = kernel / kernel.sum()                                                                  
>>>
>>> f_vert = ndimage.convolve1d(f, kernel, axis=0, mode='constant')                         
>>> f_horz = ndimage.convolve1d(f, kernel, axis=1, mode='constant')                         
>>> f_both = ndimage.convolve1d(f_vert, kernel, axis=1, mode='constant')
```

[image: original image]
original image

[image: 1D kernel applied vertically]
1D kernel applied vertically

[image: 1D kernel applied horizontally]
1D kernel applied horizontally

[image: 1D kernel applied twice]
1D kernel applied vertically, then horizontally

We can achieve the same effect in one go using the 2D outer product kernel

```
# create 2D kernel using outer product
>>> kernel2d = np.outer(kernel, kernel)
>>> f_outer = ndimage.convolve(f, kernel2d[..., None], mode='constant')
```

[image: 2D kernel used]
2D kernel used

[image: difference]
last two manipulations are equivalent as can be seen from the difference image